# Mediawiki's thumbnail handler (rewrite) doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mediawiki

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B] 

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?w/images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/w/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
```

index.php rewrite rule works, but thumbnail doesn't.
If get thumb.php directly, it works:

```
thumb.php?f=test.jpg&width=180
```

So, the problem is in rewriting. I've tried many variants, but it still doesn't work. Where may be the mistake?

Answer (score 3):

That because of `images/.htaccess`.

See [`Bug 65220`](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65220).